# Input in accordion header collapses on space key pressed

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using a accordion structure for a dynamic tab, I am stuck in a problem when pressed space button to give space between two words in the header section of the accordion it collapses, here is the link for the page [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chetanmani/gnhkm4es/11/)and the code i have used is

```
    $( ".questions" ).accordion({
        header: "> div > h3",
        collapsible: true,
        active: 0,
        autoHeight: false,
        autoActivate: true
    });



    $( "button" ).button();
    $('#addAccordion').click( function() {
        var newDiv = "<div><h3><a>Q4 New Question</a><input type='text'/name='' vlaue=''></h3><div>New Content</div></div>";
        $('.questions').append(newDiv)
        $('.questions').accordion("refresh").accordion( "option", "active", $('.questions > div').length - 1 );
    });

    $(".questions h3 input").on('keydown', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
});
```

Please can anyone help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `.on` method isn't working because the fiddle is using an old version of jQuery. Use `.bind` instead or update your version of jQuery.

Comment: doesn't seem like very friendly UX idea to begin with putting an input in accordion header

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you if it helps now.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $(".questions").accordion({
    header: "> div > h3",
    collapsible: true,
    active: 0,
    autoHeight: false,
    autoActivate: true
  });



  $("button").button();
  $('#addAccordion').click(function() {
    var newDiv = "<div><h3><a>Q4 New Question</a><input type='text'/name='' vlaue=''></h3><div>New Content</div></div>";
    $('.questions').append(newDiv)
    $('.questions').accordion("refresh").accordion("option", "active", $('.questions > div').length - 1);
  });

  $(".questions h3 input").keydown(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="questions">
  <div>
    <h3><a href="#">Question 1. My First Question ?</a>
      <input type="text" name=" " value="" /></h3>
    <div>
      First content<br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3><a href="#">Question 2. My Second Question ?</a>
      <input type="text" name=" " value="" /></h3>
    <div>
      Second content<br />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3><a href="#">Question 3. My Third Question ?</a>
      <input type="text" name=" " value="" /></h3>
    <div>
      Third content<br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="addAccordion">Add Accordion</button>
</div>
```

I have changed your `.on` to `.keydown`.